# Implicit differentiation of $3x^2 + 4y^2 = 12$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The equation $3x^2 + 4y^2 = 12$ defines $y$ implicitly as two functions of $x$ if $|x| < 2$ and $|x|=2$. Assuming
>   the second derivative $y''$ exists, show that it satisfies the equation $4y^3 y'' = -9$.

**Progress**.  I derived $6x+8yy'=0$ then $y'= \frac{-3x}{4y}$ then derived again $$y'' = \frac{-3(y-xy')}{4y^2}= \frac{-3(y-xy')y}{4y^2y}= \frac{-3(y^2-xyy')}{4y^3} $$ Then $4y^3y''= -3(y^2-xyy')$, so I want $-9 = -3(y^2-xyy')$... and don't know the rest.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck in this question? It would be useful to list the steps you have taken so far so that we can better judge where exactly you are having difficulties.

Comment: ahh? OK. I derive $6x+8yy'=0$ then $y'= \frac{-3x}{4y}$ then derive again $y'' = \frac{-3(y-xy')}{4y^2}= \frac{-3(y-xy')y}{4y^2y}= \frac{-3(y^2-xyy')}{4y^3} $ then $4y^3y''= -3(y^2-xyy')$ so I want $-9 = -3(y^2-xyy')$... and don't know the rest(How follow).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

Note that you found:
$$y'=\frac{-3x}{4y}$$
$$\therefore xyy'=\frac{-3x^2}{4}\tag{1}$$

and from the initial identity we have:$$3x^2=12-4y^2=4(3-y^2)\tag{2}$$

Now just substitute (2) into (1) and use that result to simplify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that
if
$ax^2+by^2 = c$,
then
$b^2y^3y''
=-ac
$.
In this case,
$16y^2y''
= -36$
or
$4y^2y''
= -9$.

I use implicit differentiation
*twice*.

From
$ax^2 + by^2 = c
$,
as you did
$0 
=2ax+2byy'
=ax+byy'
$,
so
$y'
=-\frac{ax}{by}
$.

Doing it again,
$0
= a+b((y')^2+yy'')
$
or
$-\frac{a}{b}
=(y')^2+yy''
=(\frac{ax}{by})^2+yy''
$
or
$-aby^2
=a^2x^2+b^2y^3y''
$
or
$b^2y^3y''
=-aby^2-a^2x^2
=-a(by^2+ax^2)
=-ac
$.

In your case,
$c = ab$,
so
$b^2y^3y''
=-a^2b
$
or
$by^3y''
=-a^2
$.